# python reports socket in use, netstat and others claim its not

Tags: networking, tcp, netstat, socket

We have a strange socket issue with a RHES3 box:

```
Python 2.4.1 (#1, Jul  5 2005, 19:17:11)
[GCC 3.2.3 20030502 (Red Hat Linux 3.2.3-52)]
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket()
>>> s.bind(('localhost',12351))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.error: (98, 'Address already in use')
```

This seems normal, lets see what has that socket:

```
# netstat -untap | grep 12351
```

{no output}

```
# grep 12351 /proc/net/tcp
```

{no output}

```
# lsof | grep 12351
```

{no output}

```
# fuser -n tcp 12351
```

{no output, repeating the python test fails again}

```
# nc localhost 12351
```

{no output}

```
# nmap localhost 12351
```

{shows port closed}

Other high ports work fine (eg 12352 works)

Is there something magic about this port? Is there somewhere else I can look? Where does python find out that socket is in use that netstat doesnt know about? Any other way I can find out what/if that socket is?

Comment: How odd, the code works for me.

Comment: Did you try adding `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` before the `bind()`?

Comment: Does telnet localhost 12351 reveal anything?

Comment: nothing from telnet, and nmap also shows the port as closed (will update post with this)

Comment: Maybe try `nc -l -p 12351` (or equivalent for your local netcat), so that we see if something else than python can bind that socket ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I had the same problem but i'll put what I found here.

I had a python server process that was bound to 8081 and Apache proxying to it using the reverse proxy module.

Looking in ps showed that the process was running:

```
UID    PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
xxxx 31896 31681  2 08:51 ?        00:00:03  \_ python /opt/xxxx/install/xxxx/xxxx/bin/content_server.py localhost:8081
```

Telnet worked fine:

```
$ telnet localhost 8081
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

However greping for the port number in netstat didn't show anything bound to that port:

```
$ netstat -a | grep 8081
$
```

Though if you check the process id in netstat you might see a line like this with "tproxy" as the port number:

```
$ netstat -a -p | grep 31896
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 MELLAGFIN01:tproxy  *:*  LISTEN  31896/python
```

Someone else can probably confirm, but i'm assuming this is some sort of kernel level tcp proxy?

Answer (score 0):

If something else can bind that socket, run strace on both and see if the system calls before the bind() are different.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible that your script does multiple socket.bind() calls.

In that case you have 'address already in use' problem on second call, but as your program crashes right after that you cannot see the opened socket.